# How to use URL as primary key using JPA and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I  have an entity which contains url of different sites, I want this column to be my primary key. I try

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MyClass{

    private String titleOfNews;
    private String description;
    @Id
    private String link;
  ...
}
```

Is it enough just to annotate the String link with @ID annotation? Or I have to do something else?

Comment: Why don't you test it and observe the result ? Check this. http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id